# JSON.parse is not working while using mcrypt

Tags: ajax, json, codeigniter, base64, mcrypt

I'm trying to use mcrypt and encrypt and decrypt json data crossing domain. Actually, this worked when I use the encryption in the same domain, but did not work in ajax.

```
Here is function all:
function all($contentType = 'page') {
    $secret_key = "12345678911234567892123456789312";
    $this->load->database();
    $query = $this->db->query(
       "SELECT * FROM category"
    );
$buffer = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret_key, json_encode($result),       MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$this->output->set_output(base64_encode($buffer));

Here is file of view: 
$(function(){
  try {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8888/DIY/index.php/user/all/json",
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    async: false,
    dataType: 'text',
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function (response) {
        var a = mcrypt.Decrypt($.base64('decode', response ));
        console.log(  JSON.parse(a) );
    },
    error: function (ErrorResponse) {
        console.log('error');
    }
});
}
catch (error) {
}
});

The output in Chrome is:
[{"id":"1","EMAIL":"sda@q.com","PHONE":"sdsng","USERNAME":"12das","FIRST_NAME":null,"LAST_NAME":null,"PASSWORD":"","TYPE":null},{"id":"2","EMAIL":"adas","PHONE":"dsada","USERNAME":"asdasd","FIRST_NAME":null,"LAST_NAME":null,"PASSWORD":"","TYPE":null}]
```

And if I add JSON.parse(a) in the view file, it will display nothing. However, after I get console.log(a) in Chrome, I directly copy the output data as the parameters, and use it in Chrome console

```
JSON.parse('[{"id":"1","EMAIL":"139520519@qq.com","PHONE":"yang_zhang","USERNAME":"122545929","FIRST_NAME":null,"LAST_NAME":null,"PASSWORD":"","TYPE":null},{"id":"2","EMAIL":"adas","PHONE":"dsada","USERNAME":"asdasd","FIRST_NAME":null,"LAST_NAME":null,"PASSWORD":"","TYPE":null}]')
[Object, Object]
```

The output is what I am looking for!!! Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Now it is solved. I change the mode of mcrypt from ecb to cfb, and pass the IV to different domain. Then using passed IV to decrypt data will get the string which can use JSON.parse() to get expected json object